# Mid-way level shift in RS485 tranmission

Tags: esp32, rs485

I have two similar devices that communicate using the RS-485 protocol with my ESP32 (through a MAX485 IC). One of them seems to have an issue midway through. Here is the scope image that shows the output of both devices.

Probing the A terminal:
[image: Probing A terminal]

Probing the B terminal:
[image: Probing B terminal]

The plot on top shows the output from the device that outputs the correct data. The RED bounding box is the Control Message that the master sends to the device. The GREEN bounding box is (first) part of the response (echoes the control message) that is sent from the device to the master.

I can see that the second (bottom) device tries to echo the control message back but it shifts mid-level, hence the erroneous (1 byte error) data received in the master. I wonder why this happens. Both the devices were plugged into the same port one by one and scoped.

I am using an ESP32 as the master. The below code stub is responsible for driving the Driver Enable:

```cpp
void loop () {
  digitalWrite(DE, HIGH);
  Serial2.write(0x02);
  digitalWrite(DE, LOW);

  Serial2.readBytes(rx, sizeof(rx));
  ...
  delay(100);
```

Here is the rough schematic showing all the connections between the device and master. It is just a regular RS485 communication setup.
[image]

Comment: Can you show more detail on how you made these measurements? RS485 uses differential signaling - did you only measure on one wire, or did you measure both wires and have your scope calculate the difference?

Comment: RS-485 is a differential bus. You only show one of the wires so it does not define if what you see on one wire only is a problem or not.

Comment: @brhans I had only probed the A terminal of RS485. I have added the scope image of B terminal too now.

Comment: @Justme I have added the B terminal scope image now.

Comment: My guess is that two devices start transmitting something at the same time.

Comment: @Justme I recorded the plot by having only one device at a time.

Comment: It looks to me as though your master is not releasing the Driver-Enable signal to its RS485 transceiver in a consistent and quick enough time period. Sometimes it does release fast enough, and the signal looks fine in those cases. Other times it's still driving Driver-Enable when the slave tries to reply.

Comment: I also confused by whether your ESP32 is the "master" or not. You start off by writing that you're communicating with 2 devices from your computer (in which case the computer would typically be the "master"), but then end off with "I am using an ESP32 as the master".

Comment: @brhans must be correct. The other device takes longer to respond so ESP32 has released the bus transmitter, other device responds faster and ESP32 is still driving the bus. Now, show which kind of schematic or module you use and what code on ESP32  is driving the transceiver?

Comment: @brhans I am sorry for the confusion. I am using my computer to see the Serial Monitor of ESP32. I shall make the edits. There is no explicit delay in my code at least after doing a master write operation. So I wonder how I can reduce the release time for Driver Enable.

Comment: @AdarshTS We don't know how you drive the Driver Enable so we don't know what's wrong with it or how to fix it. Post the schematics and code.

Comment: @Justme I am not doing anything fancy in the comm part. It is a regular rs485 setup. I have added the code stub and the rough schematic that shows the comm part of the circuit. Please do point out if I have made any mistake or if you need any more details.

Comment: (probably) unrelated to your current problem, but you're missing a GND wire between your ESP32 and your Device 1/2 alongside the RS485 A/B wires.

Comment: @brhans I was under the impression that common ground was not necessary for differential signaling.

Comment: @AdarshTS Are you sure you have only a MAX485 chip, not a ready made module? And as it is a 5V chip, you can't power it at 3.3V or connect 5V data wires to 3.3V MCU. And yes, **RS-485 transceivers require a common ground reference between them**, do search here as it has been asked before.

Comment: I am using a bare MAX485 chip and the ESP32 development board has a 5V output through which the MAX485 IC is powered. I gave a common ground connection between the device and master but the same issue persists.

Comment: Tell the oscilloscope to compute A−B. Also include the DE signals, if possible.

Comment: @AdarshTS Yes but now the MAX485 powered by 5V tries to output 5V on RO to the ESP32 which tolerates only 3.3V. You can't have that and expect it to work. Fortunately MAX485 understands TTL levels so 3.3V is a proper logic level to it.

Comment: You were under an incorrect impression (at least as far as RS485 is concerned). Look at the specs for your RS485 driver ICs - you'll find a maximum common-mode voltage rating (+12V / -7V is a typical spec). This is the maximum voltage which either A or B is allowed to reach with respect to Gnd. With no common Gnd between your 2 devices, how can you know what the common-mode voltage will be? This is in addition to arguments that RS485 is a differential voltage bus, not a current loop, and as such you need a 3rd wire to return the signaling currents from both A & B.

Comment: But back to your actual problem - in all likelihood you can't fix this while staying within the Arduino framework on your ESP32 unless you can alter the firmware in your Device1/2 to make it delay for a longer time before responding. Your ESP32 is just not consistently fast enough in getting from `Serial2.write(0x02);` to `digitalWrite(DE, LOW);`.

Comment: Add `Serial2.flush();` before `digitalWrite(DE, LOW);`. Depend on your baud rate, you may also need to introduce a frame delay, it could various from 1750uS to 4000uS (at baud rate lower than 9600). Read the Modulus spec for more details.